# WordPress PHP if no gallery image, use featured image

Tags: php, wordpress

Using WordPress, I have a gallery and featured image on my custom posttype, at the bottom of the page is a section that shows all of the other posts under the custom posttype.

I'm trying to bring back the first gallery image from the post, if there isn't a gallery image then the featured image should be used, but only the gallery image is being brought back.

Here is my code below:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'service',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order'    => 'ASC'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $count = 0;
    echo '<div class="row">';
    while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post();
    $featuredimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $thePost->ID ), 'large' );
    $images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vdw_gallery_id', true);
    if($count == 5){
        $count = 0;
        echo '</div><div class="row">';
    };
    ?>
    <div class="col- col-md service-images">
        <a href="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>">
            <?php foreach ($images as $image) {
                $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'large');
                if ( empty( $img ) ) {
                    if ($img === 0) {
                        echo '<div class="images" style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0 ,0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), url(' . $featuredimage[0] . ') background-position: center; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 100%;">';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo '<div class="images" style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0 ,0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), url(' . $img[0] . '); background-position: center; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 100%;">';
                }; ?>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="col- col-md service-block-title">
                        <h3><?php echo the_title(); ?></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php }; ?>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $count++;
endwhile;
echo '</div>';?>
</div>
```

Simply, if $img is empty (no image in the gallery) then use $featuredimage.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which image is not showing?

Comment: The featured images, I've set a gallery image for one of the posts which is displaying, but the other posts without a gallery image should be showing their featured images.

Comment: can you do like this for your featured image


`<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): 
 $featuredimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
endif; ?>`

Comment: I need it so if there is no gallery image, the featured image is used. The featured images worked before, it's just now I'm trying to incorporate the gallery.

Comment: can you tell me which of your image is not showing? gallery image or featured image?

Comment: Try to use `wp_reset_query();` at the end of your query. 
Check this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Comment: change this $thePost->ID to get_the_ID() or $query->post->ID

Comment: OR if $Post global then use $post->ID

Comment: @NewUser all  of the gallery images are showing, I've added a picture to every post, it's just the featured image that isn't showing.